# How do I find what screen the application is running on in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, screen

How do I determine what screen my application is running on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should get you started. Get a Button and a listbox on a Form and put this in the Button_Click:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(screen);
}
listBox1.SelectedItem = Screen.FromControl(this);
```

The answer is in the last line, remember that a Form is a Control too.

Answer (score 1):

The System.Windows.Forms.Screen class provides this functionaility.

For example:

Screen s = Screen.FromPoint(p);

where p is a Point somewhere on your application (in screen coordinates).

Answer (score 1):

Well, many years have passed, and it is derivative of the accepted answer, but this worked for me. This method is a member of the Form class. The `screen` variable contains the properties of the screen that the upper left corner of the form is on when the method is called.

```
private void ClsFormFoo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Screen screen = Screen.FromControl(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I don't think there is a built in way to get this, but it shouldn't be too hard to determine. Use the [Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen(VS.80).aspx) class to find all the screens, loop through that list and compare its bounds with the location of the form.

Here is some untested code

```
Screen [] screens = Screen.AllScreens;

for(index = 0; index < screens.Length; index++) {
     if (screens[index].Contains(this.Bounds))
        return screens[index];
}
```

Comment: screens.Contains() -is what you are after and if so you dont need to look though them....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these links:

- [MFC program for multiple monitors](http://www.ucancode.net/Visual_C_Codes/MFC-Example-Multiple-monitor-support-GetSystemMetrics-EnumDisplayMonitors-GetMonitorInfo%20.htm)
- [Original MSDN article for multiple monitors](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0697/monitor/monitor.aspx)

These are in WinAPI. There may be .NET multiple monitor libraries/api calls, but if not, with these you can write your own.