# In a C# winform how do identify what monitor the app is displayed on

Tags: c#

Duplicate of [How do I find what screen the application is running on in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549751/how-do-i-find-what-screen-the-application-is-running-on-in-c/549789#549789)

In a C# winform how do identify what monitor the app is displayed on in a three monitor setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromControl()
```

Retrieves a Screen for the display that contains the largest portion of the specified control.

And also this Property might be helpfull:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens
```

Gets an array of all displays on the system.

Comment: You have no idea how long I have been looking for this answer, thanks!!