# WPF C# Create an array for Screen.AllScreens and display all values within a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to do something simple and seem to be struggling. Using the answer on another question:

[Is there a way to invoke the "Identify Monitors" function from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418623/is-there-a-way-to-invoke-the-identify-monitors-function-from-c)

I am trying to create the array and display all values. How should I be doing that?

```
foreach (Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens as $item)
        {
            listBox.Items.Add($item);
        }
```

Comment: `listBox.ItemsSource = Screen.AllScreens.Select(s => s.DeviceName);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do -

```
foreach (Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens)
{
      listBox.Items.Add(screen.DeviceName); // Or whatever property you to bind
}
```

`AllScreens` is already an array.

**Update**

And yes, as suggested in comment we can directly use `ItemsSource` property instead of looping.

I completely missed `wpf` tag on your question, I assumed you are working on `WinForms` as the question you have linked was related to WinForms

```
listBox.ItemsSource = Screen.AllScreens.Select(x => x.DeviceName);
```

Comment: You made me realize how not straight I was thinking... Thank you.

Comment: If this answered your question please mark it as answer :)