# run application on a dual screen environment

Tags: c#, .net, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find what screen the application is running on in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549751/how-do-i-find-what-screen-the-application-is-running-on-in-c-sharp)

Any ideas to check whether current application is run on primary screen or not in a dual screen environment? I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5. I want to add code in my application to detect whether current application is run on primary screen or not.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Screen class which can tell you whether or not a control is on a particular screen or not.  You can also get the primary monitory, and every Screen object also has a Primary property which indicates whether or not it is the primary monitory.

Here's the [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen_members.aspx).

You should be able to use it like this:

```
var monitor = Screen.FromControl(this);

if (monitor.Primary) //the monitor returned is the primary monitor
```

Answer (score 1):

NOT TESTED: (don't have a dual screen setup at the moment to test on)

```
bool onPrimary = this.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds);
```

where "this" is the main form of your application.

**EDIT:** Just tested it, it works as expected.