# How do I know what monitor a WPF window is in

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In a C# application, how can I find out if a WPF window is in the primary monitor or another monitor?

Comment: Odds are good that it will be on both.

Comment: @Helen that question applies to Winforms, this is for WPF which is different.

Answer (score 36):

If the window is maximized then you cannot rely on window.Left or window.Top at all since they may be the coordinates before it was maximized. But you can do this in all cases:

```
    var screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromHandle(
       new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle);
```

Comment: I'm getting the screen where it was opened, not the current one.

Answer (score 11):

Other replies available so far don't address the WPF part of the question. Here's my take.

WPF doesn't seem to expose detailed screen info as found in Windows Forms' Screen class mentioned in other replies.

However, you can use the WinForms Screen class in your WPF program:

Add references to `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Drawing`

```
var screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromRectangle(
  new System.Drawing.Rectangle(
    (int)myWindow.Left, (int)myWindow.Top, 
    (int)myWindow.Width, (int)myWindow.Height));
```

*Note that if you are a nitpicker, you may have noted that this code could have right and bottom coordinates off by one pixel in some case of double to int conversions. But since you are a nitpicker, you will be more than happy to fix my code ;-)*

Comment: It also does not work with non-default DPI. Especially, different per-monitor DPI.

Answer (score 8):

In order to do that you need to use some native methods.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145064(v=vs.85).aspx

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    public const Int32 MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY = 0x00000001;
    public const Int32 MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 0x00000002;

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    public static extern IntPtr MonitorFromWindow( IntPtr handle, Int32 flags );
}
```

Then you simply check in which monitor your window is and which is the primary one. Like this:

```
        var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper( this ).EnsureHandle();
        var currentMonitor = NativeMethods.MonitorFromWindow( hwnd, NativeMethods.MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST );
        var primaryMonitor = NativeMethods.MonitorFromWindow( IntPtr.Zero, NativeMethods.MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY );
        var isInPrimary = currentMonitor == primaryMonitor;
```

Comment: R.Rusev  this return the hwn of monitor?
Then how can use that hwnd for know what monitor number is?
I mean the numbers windows show on the display config.
There is a way to get that number and know on what number of monitor is running my wpf window?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool IsOnPrimary(Window myWindow)
{
    var rect = myWindow.RestoreBounds;
    Rectangle myWindowBounds= new Rectangle((int)rect.X, (int)rect.Y, (int)rect.Width, (int)rect.Height);
    return myWindowBounds.IntersectsWith(WinForms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds);

    /* Where
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Windows;
        using WinForms = System.Windows.Forms;
     */
}
```

Comment: Note that `myWindow.RestoreBounds` does not return the window's real size and position if the window is anchored left or right on a screen. (Windows button + arrow left or right) In that case, you should use myWindow.Left, myWindow.Right, myWindow.Width and myWindow.Height.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [How do I find what screen the application is running on in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549751/how-do-i-find-what-screen-the-application-is-running-on-in-c/549789#549789)
Also [Run Application on a Dual Screen Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039979/run-application-on-a-dual-screen-environment) has an interesting solution:

```
bool onPrimary = this.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds);
```

where "this" is the main form of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
if (Screen.AllScreens.Length < 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have just one monitor!");
    return;
}

string primaryMonitor = "";
string currentMonitor = Screen.FromHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle).DeviceName;

for (int i = 0; i < Screen.AllScreens.Length; i++)
{
    if (Screen.AllScreens[i].Primary == true)
    {
        primaryMonitor = Screen.AllScreens[i].DeviceName;
    }
}

if (currentMonitor == primaryMonitor)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Window is in primary monitor ({primaryMonitor})");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Window is in ({currentMonitor}) and primary monitor is ({primaryMonitor})");
}
```

However, there may be a shorter way to get primary monitor.

Comment: You can skip all the looping, and where you find the device name just check primary:
`Screen.FromHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle).Primary`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I've been searching for a solution for a while, to properly maximize window/windows in a multi-monitor multi-resolution setup. This is how I get the primary screen.

```
 //Get the screen that the window is currently on
  System.Windows.Forms.Screen currentScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromHandle(new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(<<your System.Windows.Window instance>>).Handle);

  if (currentScreen.Primary)
  {
      //do something
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [`Screen.FromControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.fromcontrol.aspx) method to get the current screen for the current form like this:

```
Screen screen = Screen.FromControl(this);
```

Then you can check [`Screen.Primary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primary.aspx) to see if the current screen is the primary screen.

Comment: A WPF `Window` is not a Forms `Control`, thus you CANNOT use `Screen.FromControl(this)` in this case.

Comment: However, you can use: Screen.FromHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);