# How do I prevent the taskbar from appearing with a WPF non-fullscreen window?

Tags: wpf, window, command-line-interface

I have a large C++ codebase with native Windows GUI that runs fullscreen.
A part of it shall be exchanged by a WPF window shown on top of it.
The window is set up like this:

```
<Window WindowState="Normal" 
        WindowStyle="None"
        ShowInTaskbar="False"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
/>
```

This blends the window seamless into the rest of the application.
The invocation of the window is done from C++/CLI like this:

```
Windows::Window^ w = window();
Windows::Interop::WindowInteropHelper iHelp(w);
iHelp.Owner = System::IntPtr(_parentHwnd);
w->Show();
```

The _parentHwnd is the HWND of the native application.
As said the application is always shown fullscreen.
When I now click on the WPF window the Windows taskbar will appear.
How do I **prevent the taskbar from appearing**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this class (an idea was found somewhere on the Net) to hide/show the taskbar:

```
public static class Taskbar
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int FindWindow(string className, string windowText);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int command);

    private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    private const int SW_SHOW = 1;

    public static int Handle
    {
        get
        {
            return FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
        }
    }
    public static int StartHandle
    {
        get
        {
            return FindWindow("Button", "Start");
        }
    }

    public static void Show()
    {
        ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOW);
        ShowWindow(StartHandle, SW_SHOW);
    }

    public static void Hide()
    {
        ShowWindow(Handle, SW_HIDE);
        ShowWindow(StartHandle, SW_HIDE);
    }
}
```

Works on Windows XP/Vista/7.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I test that out - might take a day before I come back.

Comment: Interesting. I consider this a serious hack but fills our needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With Flot2011 answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465646) I was able to pretend that my window belongs to another fullscreen window. For those curious about the missing parts - here are they:
We implement handler for the activated and deactivated events

```
<Window
Activated="DisplayWindow_Activated"
Deactivated="DisplayWindow_Deactivated"
/>
```

The event handler look like this

```
private void DisplayWindow_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromRectangle(
    new System.Drawing.Rectangle(
      (int)this.Left, (int)this.Top,
      (int)this.Width, (int)this.Height));
  if( screen.Primary )
    Taskbar.Hide();
}

private void DisplayWindow_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromRectangle(
    new System.Drawing.Rectangle(
      (int)this.Left, (int)this.Top,
      (int)this.Width, (int)this.Height));
  if( screen.Primary )
    Taskbar.Show();
}
```

So what happens now? The taskbar will vanish in the main application because it is fullscreen. When I click on the overlaid window the taskbar would be activated but is deactivated by the propert event. So the mashup behaves like one fullscreen application.

The `screen` part is to handle multi-monitor setups. We should only hide the taskbar if the (mashup) application is shown fullscreen on the primary monitor. The current solution assumes that WPF-window and underlying fullscreen application are on the same screen.

If you use the `screen` stuff, don't forget to include references to `System.Drawing` and `System.Window.Forms`. Usings are not such a great idea here because the namespaces collide with stuff from .net.