# Moving WPF application between screens/certain coordinates

Tags: wpf, screen

I'm trying to make an application in WPF that has 2 buttons which will handle the 2 screens I have. One button would move the application to the main screen and the other to the secondary screen. Is this possible in WPF and if so, would anyone tell me how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an all-purpose solution but in your specific case, you could simply set  values for `window.Left` and `window.Top`.

See [this SO question for more details on screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465646/how-do-i-know-what-monitor-a-wpf-window-is-in)