# vb.net determine Screen

Tags: vb.net, winforms, screen

Is it possible to determine the screen where a form is located? Not the position or the Size!

I used

```
Dim myScreens() As Screen = Screen.AllScreens

Me.Left = (myScreens(0).WorkingArea.Width - Me.Size.Width) / 2
Me.Top = (myScreens(0).WorkingArea.Height - Me.Size.Height) / 2
```

to postion the Form. When the user relocates the form onto another screen, I want to save that postion of that new screen!

Comment: Careful with this! It's easy to get it wrong by displaying the form on a monitor that no longer exists. You'll need to verify that when you read the saved value and go to restore the form to its previous position. If it would be off the screen, you will need to revert to a default position.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, use [`Screen.FromControl(Me)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.fromcontrol.aspx).

> Retrieves a Screen for the display that contains the largest portion of the specified control.

Comment: What about WPF ? Is there a way i can get the screen without referencing winforms stuff?

Comment: The question has been [asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465646/how-do-i-know-what-monitor-a-wpf-window-is-in), where the answer appears to be "no", sorry.