# Define if an owned form has loaded at the same screen of it's owner form

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a project with owner and owned forms. There is any way to define if an owned form has loaded at the same screen of it's owner form? Sorry I didn't came up with a code example but I couldn't find something similar to show!!!

Comment: When you say "at the same screen", are you referring to a physical monitor?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer: Yes!!!

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963552/vb-net-determine-screen ?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer: I am already using this `Me.MaximumSize = Screen.FromControl(Me).WorkingArea.Size` but how can I define if this screen is the primary or any other screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the `Screen` object returned from `Screen.FromControl(Me)`

```
  Private Sub ScreenTestButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ScreenTestButton.Click
        Try
            Dim thisScreen As Screen = Screen.FromControl(Me)
            If thisScreen.Primary Then
                MessageBox.Show("I'm on the primary screen")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("I'm not on the primary screen")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("Something went wrong: ", ex.Message))
        End Try
    End Sub
```