# Don't hide taskbar on maximized window with multi screen

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application WPF. My main Windows as :

```
<Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
```

When I set :

```
Window.GetWindow(this).WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized
```

The window goes in full screen. It's ok on my secondary screen, but it hide taskbar on my primary screen. I have try o use `SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight` but it makes trouble on the secondary. And in WPF I don't know how to detect the actual screen.

Someone has a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that there is no native WPF function to get the monitor resolution, but if you are using multiple screens [these functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145072(VS.85).aspx) might catch your interest.

Comment: I just had a look at your like but it seems to be working for c++. Actually i'm developing on C#. Or Maybe it's a problem of reference for my projet

Answer (score 0):

With the help of `Dominik K` I finally find this post [How do I know what monitor a WPF window is in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465646/how-do-i-know-what-monitor-a-wpf-window-is-in) and use the solution with :

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    public const Int32 MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMERTY = 0x00000001;
    public const Int32 MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 0x00000002;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr MonitorFromWindow(IntPtr handle, Int32 flags);
}
```

It's work without using Forms functions

Comment: This is old, but i came across similar issue.

So I have a question regarding above, how did you manage to access Width, Height and Top/Left position of monitor to properly maximize it? :)